# Run SQL script on PostgreSQL with password supplied

Tags: java, psql

I'm trying to run an SQL-script from within my Java app. This is my code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("setx PGPASSWORD \"" + password + "\"");
String command = String.format("psql -d %s -h %s -p %s -U %s -w -f %s",
        database, host, port, user, "create_tables.sql");
System.out.println("Executing command " + command);
Process p = rt.exec(String.format(command));
p.waitFor();
```

This prints

```
psql -d routes -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -f create_tables.sql
```

as expected.

However within my databases log I see the following:

> psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

How do I supply the password to `psql` when calling it as process?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Your edit causes some confusion as `psql` and Postgres aren´t the same things. Psql is just the shell provided by postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment variable should be set in the same process as the `psql` is executed. This does not happen in your code as you execute two different processes.

The thing is, that environment variables are local to process contexts.

A new process gets a copy of the parent's environment but each copy is independent. 
In your case, the `Java` process creates child process that modifies `PGPASSWORD` through `setx` command - so far so good.

However,  this doesn't affect the `Java` process. Your second child process isn't running in a `shell`, so it ignores the  `PGPASSWORD` variable as the process is created using `OS` services. Those services, take into consideration the old context of the `Java` process which is not aware of `PGPASSWORD` unless you change the environment in the shell before you start the original (parent) `Java` process.

Thus,to solve your problem, you have to set up the environment variable and then   run the child as a shell command (`cmd /c`). 
To set up environment variable we could follow @Little Santi's advice.

So the code would look something like the following

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String setCommand="PGPASSWORD=" + password;

String command = String.format("psql -d %s -h %s -p %s -U %s -w -f %s", 
        database, host, port, user, "create_tables.sql");

String finalCommand = "cmd /c \" " + command +"\"";
System.out.println("Executing command " + finalCommand);

Process p = rt.exec(finalCommand ,new String[]{setCommand});
p.waitFor();
```

**Edit 2:**

Comment: I still get the same error. I added a watch to `multiCommands` though and was supprised: `cmd /c "start setx PGPASSWORD=xxx && psql -d routes -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -f create_tables.sql"`

Comment: @HimBromBeere I see have you tired doing the above manually (dos prompt - command line) does it work then? also why there is `=` sign in your `setx` command? Isn't it a wrong syntax?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I edited my answer  - please try it out - and also tell me if you may what is now `multiCommands` looks like...

Comment: Interesting, the `/V`-option lead to a "password-authentication failed"-error, however with `start`-option I get it at least via command-line with both `set` and `setx`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You mean with `start` it worked? could it be working because of an earlier  `setx` which have put the password into registry?  I didn't notice at the beginning that you have been using `setx` which is changing the registry ... Hmm now I have another theory why your code didn't work - may be you just  should have added `waitfor()` after `setx`. Also  after running your original code - check the registry if the value have been set...

Comment: On command-line all three options work, with `/V`, `start setx PGPWASSWORD xxx` and `start set PGPASSWORD=xxx`.

Comment: Indeed, the variable was set permamnently, checked it by opening new shell and typing `set PGPASSWORD`. Returned `xxx`. Anyway I guess you mean envirenmoement-variable, not registry, do you?

Comment: You´re right, it worked only because the variable was stored permanently. I reset it and now it does not work any more, neither with `set` nor `setx`.

Comment: So, 2 thing to determine 1. if you set variable permanently via `setx` (manually - in command line)  and then run your code (only the `psql` part ) - does it work?  2. (if 1 does work) does  running 'setx' in code with `waitfor()` change environment variable permanently ?

Comment: So by using `Process p = rt.exec(multipleCommands,new String[]{setCommand});` we´re creating two child-processes of our main-process that share the same variables, right? Going to try this out in some hours.

Comment: I finally got it to work with your help. However I had to set the working-directory also this is setting a `File`-instance as third argument to `Runtime.exec`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Good to hear that it finally worked! ;-) I assume working directory was needed so that `psql` executable  and  `.sql` file were located. That could have been achieved also, if you have set `path` environment variable to point to `psql` executable and provided full path to `.sql`. But, setting working directory is fine too... The important thing is that code works - everything else is mere details ;-)

Comment: Actually `psql` *is* added to `PATH`-viarable. Check this by opening a simple shell and typed `psql` resulting in psql´s help being promted. As per the docs when not providing any working-directory the directory is taken from the hosting process - which is the path to java.exe.

Answer (score 0):

@Plirkee's diagnosis is right: The process in which you start `psql` misses the required environment variable. But to set it on properly it's better to use the [Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])) method.